# Button enabling for multiple file uploads - HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in my html where I'm to upload three files. The submit button for all the corresponding file uploads is disabled unless a file is selected.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('input:file').change(
      function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
          $('input:submit').attr('disabled', false);
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="fileInput1" id="fileInput1" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />
</form>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="fileInput2" id="fileInput2" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />
</form>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="fileInput3" id="fileInput3" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />
</form>
```

My concern is that, if I select a file for the first form, the submit button in the other forms too get enabled.

Comment: What is the desired result? Why do you have _three_ `<form>`s? Why do you have three submit buttons? Why not just upload three files with one `<input type="file">`?

Comment: These forms are under different div tags,which are under different sidebar options. I have just taken out the forms to be of easier and precise understanding. The three files cannot be uploaded at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
Regardless of the order of the elements, this will enable the wanted button:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $('form input:file').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {
                    // Select button of this form
                    $(this).parent('form')
                        .children('input:submit')
                        .attr('disabled',false);
            } 
        }
    );
});
```

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jehadnasser/n7v2yetg/)

**Option 2:** This will enable it in case Input-submit is always next to Input-File:

```
$(this).next().attr('disabled',false);
```

instead of this:

```
$('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
```

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jehadnasser/ta52dmpn/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use traversing, to find the right button within the right form.

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $(this).siblings('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled',false); 
                } 
            }
            );
    });
```

This will look only for inputs that are siblings of the file input, which means that they are within the same parent element (in your case, the same form).

Comment: This was what I was expecting for ! Thank you Victoria. But what if the forms are under different div? Will this be working?